# How to run all project's tests from REPL?

Tags: testing, clojure, leiningen

How to run all leiningen project's tests from REPL? Leiningen's `lein test` does this. How to do it from the REPL?

Comment: Any idea why you don't want to use Leiningen or Maven for example?

Comment: @Chiron I can think of one reason to choose the repl over maven or lein: while developing, running tests from the REPL is typically orders of magnitude faster compared with lein test.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat please note that I didn't say it is a silly idea.

Comment: @Chiron I did not mean to imply you did. I will change the comment.

Comment: @Chiron the question is how to run the equivalent of `lein test` from the REPL, with the JVM already running, not from the CLI. As to why, as @Joost mentioned, it is much faster and can be integrated into other interactive development routines that live within the JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run all currently loaded tests by calling `(clojure.test/run-all-tests)`.

Note that that does not automatically *load* the tests you want to run. If your tests can be run via "lein test" you should be able to `require` the test namespaces like any other namespace.

If you're using emacs with CIDER, you should also be able to do `C-c ,` in a namespace to run its tests (this *will* load that test if it wasn't loaded before).

Comment: `run-all-tests` runs dependencies' tests as well. At least it prints `Testing x` for every dependency. `lein test` in comparison only runs tests defined in the current leiningen project.

Comment: I think the missing piece is finding out which tests are actually part of the "current project", and clojure.test does not involve itself with the notion of projects, just with whatever is loaded into the current clojure program (most of the time, dependencies' tests are not loaded, but it checks for tests on every loaded package). My current workflow is to run `cider-test-run-tests` from Emacs for quick test/code feedback on the current package, and run `lein test` to test the whole project from fresh in the background.

Comment: I agree. I intend to ask another question on the lines of "how to get a list of current project's namespaces."